# How show picture from String

Tags: android, imageview, image

I have a problem with pictures. I have a picture in `picture=sites/default/files/arrow_green_right_0.png`. In my application I get only this String. I want to show picture from this String in my imageView. How I can do that?

Comment: did you copied the picture in your project.?

Comment: put this pictute into drawable folder

Comment: I can't do that. This photo must be in this place. Only what I got is this String

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
ImageView img = new ImageView(this);
File file = new File(YOUR PATH TO THE IMAGE);
if (file.exists()) {
   img.setImageURI(Uri.fromFile(file));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Hi You have to set the path of the image first and make sure you handle it with exception to avoid it from crashing. follow the below code:-

```
File imgFile = new  File(“/sdcard/Images/test_image.jpg”);
 if(imgFile.exists()){

Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());

ImageView myImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageviewTest);
myImage.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);

}
```